# Standard error of proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, standard-error, inference, z-test

In the first example of http://statisticshelp.com/confidence-interval Standard error of proportion is $$\frac{\sqrt {p(1-p)}}{n}$$

Why ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want some sort of derivation of this equation? Or what?

Comment: @PeterFlom I know that if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $\bar X\sim  N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. What is the idea of the above SE for $p$?

Comment: Can you write out the expression for the standard deviation of a Bernoulli variable?  You should be able to work it out from the definition of standard deviation.

Comment: @jbowman i found it $$\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$ But in the linked page there isn't  $\sqrt$ in the denominator(n).

Comment: Ah, I see your problem!  I hadn't paid enough attention to exactly what was written, my apologies.  The $n$ should be included under the $\sqrt$ sign.  I'm guessing, from the evident LaTeX problems on the rest of the linked page, that the author simply didn't get the formatting correct.  Good catch!

Comment: "*Why ?*" -- simply a mistake by the author; I'd expect that they know the right formula and it will simply be a typing error.